MS Excel - create table which filters input data based on criteria, including input data headings
I’m trying to get my head around an excel formula but am struggling… any help would be appreciated.
Scenario
Input Data:
I have a table detailing a list of people and dates on which they are to perform various tasks.



Name
Organisation
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3




James
Tesco
19/10/2024
11/10/2024
13/10/2024


Hannah
Sainsbury
16/11/2024
19/12/2024
01/12/2024


Sarah
Tesco
18/11/2024
16/11/2024
01/12/2024


Jane
Asda
20/08/2024
09/08/2024
01/11/2024


Phil
M&S
22/11/2024
12/12/2024
06/11/2024



Output Data:
I’m looking to create a table that shows which tasks are out of date and for whom. This would involve getting:

The names of people who have an out-of-date task
The header showing which task is out of date
The date of the task

Assuming the date is 14/10/2024 the output for the above input data would look like:



Name
Organisation
Task
Date




Jane
Asda
Task 1
20/08/2024


James
Tesco
Task 3
13/10/2024


Jane
Asda
Task 2
09/08/2024



I was planning on using the “Filter” function, however whilst this will give me a list of Names/Organisations for people who have outstanding tasks, I don’t believe I can use it to show what task is outstanding or the date.
Is what I’m looking to do possible, or have I reached the limit of Excel functions?
Thanks in advance for any help.

This date 11/10/2024 for Task 2 of James should be 10/11/2024 as you are using dd/mm/yyyy otherwise the output should have shown the Task 2  for James as well.

Good spot. You're quite right!

Here is one way of accomplishing the desired output using MS365 functions:


• Formula used in cell A8
=LET(
     _Name, A2:A6,
     _Org, B2:B6,
     _Task, C2:E6,
     _Thead, C1:E1,
     _Temp, TOCOL(IFS(_Task<G2,_Name&"|"&_Org&"|"&_Thead&"|"&_Task),2),
     _Output, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&_Temp,"|",SEQUENCE(,4)),"|"),
     IFERROR(--_Output,_Output))



Thanks Mayukh, that's a neat solution which I should be able to adapt to the specifics of my situation.
Out of interest is there a method using a Filter/Lookup function that I missed?

As a follow-up. How would I go about showing tasks that are between two dates?
I tried nesting an AND in the IFS but this returns an #N/A
_Temp, TOCOL(IFS(AND(_Task<G2,_Task>G3),_Name&"|"&_Org&"|"&_Thead&"|"&_Task),2),

This : IFS((_Task<=H2)*(_Task>=G2),_Name&"|"&_Org&"|"&_Thead&"|"&_Task)

Works great. Thank you :-)

Thanks . Glad to know it worked for you.
